# Fast replacing of values in a large vectors

Tags: r

Let's suppose I have a very large vector:

```
set.seed(1)
my.vec <- runif(n = 1000000, min = -20, max = 20)
```

Now I would like to replace the values below -5 and above 5 with `NA`. This can be done by using a loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(my.vec)) {
  if (my.vec[i] < -5 | my.vec[i] > 5) {
    my.vec[i] = NA
  } else {
    my.vec[i] = my.vec[i]
  }
}
```

Even though it is not the case in this simple example, the problem with this is that it takes quite a long time when the data structure is a bit more complicated (for example when it is applied on nested data frames in a list).

This is why I was wondering if there are faster and more efficient ways to replace certain values by `NA` than using a loop with conditions?

Anybody with a hint?

Comment: You shouldn't use loop for this. `my.vec[my.vec < -5 | my.vec > 5] <- NA` works.

Comment: Thanks Ronak Shah, exactly what I was looking for! You should have posted it in the answers section :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
my.vec[my.vec < -5 | my.vec > 5] <- NA
```

Or:

```
my.vec[my.vec < -5 | my.vec > 5] = NA
```

Or use `ifelse`:

```
my.vec = ifelse((my.vec < -5 | my.vec > 5), NA, my.vec)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
my.vec[abs(my.vec) > 5] <- NA
```

Comment: Neat, it's much faster than using `|`.

Answer (score 1):

Function `is.na<-` is meant for this.

```
is.na(x) <- my.vec < -5 | my.vec > 5
```

or, following [Yuriy's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69343676/8245406),

```
is.na(my.vec) <- abs(my.vec) > 5
```